# how to prevent the word breaking when i use css styles to div tag?

Tags: html, css

hi all I am new to use css styles,

when i use the below code the complete word is splitting into two words and is moving to next line , I am not getting the complete text in a well paragraphed styles.

```
<div style="float:left; display:block;  word-wrap:break-word; width: 250px">                                                                   
<asp:Label ID="bodyLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>  
</div>
```

here i am binding the mail message to label at run time.

How to get the text wrap automatically when content applied to it without splitting the  word.

can anyone suggest how to implement this?

thanks in advance

Comment: @Daniel Casserly thank you for your advice but, i am not getting the answer what i want.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to remove `word-wrap:break-word` from your style. That is breaking your words.
Edit to make your text wrap you can set the width of the paragraph or the containing div to a specific size

example:

`width: 400px`

UPDATE:

```
<div class="text">
    <asp:Label ID="bodyLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.text {
   float:left; width: 250px; white-space: normal;
}
```

i am not sure how asp renders  i am assuming it becomes a  tag

```
div.text label {
   display:block; width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @lbrahim Diallo thank you for your reply, if i remove the word-wrap:break-word the text is going beyond the size, is there anyway to control the text to adjust with in the size?

Comment: yes using the width property, you can set a constant width, so no matter how long your text is it will always stays within, and wrap around, i will add some extra code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_white-space.asp) property, like:

```
.myTextClass {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Update:  And judging from the code you just posted, you also probably want to get rid of that `word-wrap` style.

Answer (score 0):

CSS2 has a number of properties that define how a paragraph of text is laid out:

- `white-space`     Specifies how white-space inside an element is handled
- `word-spacing`    Increases or decreases the space between words in a text
- `line-height`     Sets the line height
- `text-align`      Specifies the horizontal alignment of text
- `text-indent`     Specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block

It's actually default behavior for text to wrap and be split on whole words. To ensure it does you can set `white-space:nowrap`, but I'm not sure you need to do that in your case.

The behavior you're describing is most likely caused by the `word-wrap:break-word` property you have in your code. The [word-wrap](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap) property was invented by Microsoft and added to CSS3. It allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line.

You have defined that long words can simply be broken in half when they don't fit. Removing this rule from the `style` attribute will give you back the default behavior. If not you can change the rule to `word-wrap:normal` to be sure.